# How to change the data storage place in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

When add a new data storage in geoserver,the url will be a local address.What if I want to direct this url to a remote server address?The data are storing at the amazon server.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1):

This pretty much depends on what kind of format we are talking about, it's impossible to give a general answer.

For file based store like geotiff and shapefile it might not work at if you use direct HTTP it would work if you map a remote desk (no idea if/how you can do that with AWS) hwever performance would be, to be optimistic, suboptimal!

Simone.